# Creating subplots from lists with loop. Causes data to plot to both subplots

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I am trying to create a figure with two subplots by using a loop, but the data for each keeps getting plotted to both subplots. Here is an example of what I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_graph = []

plot_1 = []
plot_2 = []

line_1 = 1
line_2 = 2
line_3 = 3
line_4 = 4

class Plots:
    def __init__(self, list_of_lines = []):
        self.list_of_lines = list_of_lines

    def append_line(self, newLine):
            self.list_of_lines.append(newLine)

plot_1 = Plots()
plot_1.append_line(line_1)
plot_1.append_line(line_2)
my_graph.append(plot_1)

plot_2 = Plots()
plot_2.append_line(line_3)
plot_2.append_line(line_4)
my_graph.append(plot_2)

def plotting(graph):
    fig, axes = (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(8,6))
    for x in range(len(graph)):
        for line in graph[x].list_of_lines:
            axes[x].axhline(y=line)


plotting(my_graph)
```

And, when this is run, it gives me two subplots with all 4 lines on both. But, what I am trying to achieve is having `line_1` and `line_2` on the first subplot and `line_3` and `line_4` on the second subplot.

If anyone has a fix, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after playing around with it, I found a solution:

In the `__init__` block of my class:

```
class Plots:
    def __init__(self, list_of_lines = []):
        self.list_of_lines = list_of_lines

    def append_line(self, newLine):
            self.list_of_lines.append(newLine)
```

I changed it to:

```
class Plots:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_lines = []

    def append_line(self, newLine):
            self.list_of_lines.append(newLine)
```

And that fixed the issue. I'm not sure why, but something with defining the class variables the original way I did brought up the issue. Regardless, it is fixed.
Hopefully this will help others that are trying to create plots with classes.